# SQL - Account for Duplicates in Stat Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a sqlserver database for our Tax System and I'm working on stats to find Revenue and Counts (volume) for different payment types. Batch payments (mortgage company pays your property tax), Cash, and check payments are fairly simple. However the online and credit card payments are not as easy to get stats for. Online payments and Creditcard payments are both thrown into one bucket (field or column) CreditCardAmt. When someone makes an online payment the database shows the payment as teller CTO_WEB so this works fine for counting positive payments. However if the payment is reversed for whatever reason a human does it so CTO_WEB is not the teller it could be CTOTSK etc..This also throws off point of sale credit card stats. So to account for point of sale payments you can do something like if CreditCardAmt is greater than 0 and Teller != CTO_WEB then count it. However Payments that are reversed are always going to be a human with a different teller ID so Online and POS payment reversals get intermingled.

I thought well one way I could possibly account for this is using Receipt Numbers (ReceiptNum). Our Receipt Numbers start over each tax year back to #1 so I need to filter by Taxyear. if a person makes a payment online and they get receipt number 34 if that payment is reversed the row where it is reversed will also be receipt number 34. So I need a way to account for a payment being teller CTOWEB then being reversed with a different teller but same receipt number. I also need to figure out how then separate that volume and revenue from the Point of sale payment positive and reversals.

Here is what I have right now. I'm guessing I will need to add some sort of sub query to do all this?

Hope all this makes sense and I appreciate any help.

```
SELECT 
    Year(PayDtTm) AS PayYear, Month(PayDtTm) AS PayMonth, 
    SUM(PaymentAmt) AS TotalRevenue, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN PaymentAmt <  0 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END) AS Volume,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Teller = 'CTO_BTCH' THEN PaymentAmt ElSE 0 END) AS BatchRev, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Teller = 'CTO_BTCH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BatchVol,
    SUM(CashAmt) AS CashRev, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN CashAmt < 0 THEN -1 WHEN CashAmt > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS VolCash,
    SUM (CheckAmt) As CombinedCheckRev,
    SUM (CASE WHEN CheckAmt < 0 THEN -1 WHEN CheckAmt > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As CombinedVolCheck, 
    SUM(CreditCardAmt) AS CCRevenue, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN CreditCardAmt < 0 THEN -1 WHEN CreditCardAmt > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As VolCC,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Teller = 'CTO_WEB' THEN PaymentAmt ELSE 0 END) AS OnlineRev,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Teller = 'CTO_WEB' AND PaymentAmt < 0 THEN -1 WHEN Teller = 'CTO_WEB' AND PaymentAmt > 0 THEN 1 END) As OnlineVol,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Teller != 'CTO_WEB' AND CreditCardAmt > 0 THEN CreditCardAmt END) As POSRev,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Teller != 'CTO_WEB' AND CreditCardAmt > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As VolPOS
FROM [CTO].[dbo].[vReceiptMasterAdj]
WHERE PayDtTm >= '9/1/2019' and PayDtTm < '10/1/2019'
GROUP BY Year(PayDtTm), Month(PayDtTm)
ORDER BY Year(PayDtTm), Month(PayDtTm);
```

That will give me these results like this which is what I want. However the stats are not entirely correct

[image: stats]

Here is the table (view) I'm doing stats off of:

[image: table view]

Here is an example of a web payment being reversed:

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I edited the original post and showed what  I want my results to be, and added what table looks like I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to add ReceiptNr to the Group By and use Row_Number() to determine if it belongs in the Online/POS category.

A very generic example would be:

```
SELECT PayYear, PayMonth, ReceiptNum...
    CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN RowNr = 1 And Teller = 'CTO_WEB' 
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN SUM(PaymentAmt) ELSE 0 END AS OnlineRev,
    CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN RowNr = 1 And Teller = 'CTO_WEB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
      THEN SUM(CASE WHEN PaymentAmt < 0 THEN -1 WHEN PaymentAmt > 0 THEN 1 END) ELSE 0 END As OnlineVol,
    CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN RowNr = 1 And Teller = != 'CTO_WEB' 
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN SUM(CreditCardAmt) ELSE 0 END As POSRev,
    CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN RowNr = 1 And Teller = != 'CTO_WEB' 
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN SUM(CASE WHEN CreditCardAmt > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ELSE 0 END As VolPOS
FROM
(
    SELECT Year(PayDtTm) AS PayYear, Month(PayDtTm) AS PayMonth, ReceiptNum,
    Row_Number() Over(Partition By Year(PayDtTm), Month(PayDtTm), ReceiptNum Order By RevenueID) AS RowNr,
    PaymentAmt, Teller, etc...  
    FROM [CTO].[dbo].[vReceiptMasterAdj]
    WHERE PayDtTm >= '9/1/2019' and PayDtTm < '10/1/2019'
) A
GROUP BY PayYear, PayMonth, ReceiptNum
ORDER BY PayYear, PayMonth
```

The idea is to test the first row to determine what category it falls into, then do the summing.  This assumes you have some sort of primary key field like RevenueID in the original records to sort by.